# Java Map get value from key

Tags: java

i want to get value from key using following code.

```
 for (Entry<Integer, String> entryName : MainActivity.list1) {                      
 if (entry.getKey() == (entryName.getKey()))
 }
```

How can I get value if my entryName Map has key using entryName.getkey() ?

Comment: Use `entryName.getValue()`?

Comment: Why are you looping over a `Map` and comparing keys? Unless you are doing something fancy this defeats the concept of a `Map`.

Comment: Just use `MainActivity.list1.get(Integer.valueOf(somekey))`

Answer (score -1):

```
    Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();     
    myMap.put("Assembly", "One");       
    myMap.put("Prliament", "Two");      

    Integer key=2;
     for(Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()){
        if(key == entry.getKey()){
           System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        break; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: How should an `Integer` ever equals() an `String` ??